# MYSQL Not equal to "IN" query

Tags: mysql, where-clause, where-in

I have a table with loads of id's but I don't want to select around 10 id's

First I tried multiple OR but that didn't work then found the IN

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (10, 88, 99)
```

But this selects those numbers I want all the other numbers so a not equal to needs to go in somewhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (10, 88, 99)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

```
Select * from table where Id NOT IN (10,88,99)
```

Comment: That doesnt work but 
`Select * from table where NOT Id IN (10,88,99)`
Does

Comment: @StevenDale: see [the documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in): "_expr NOT IN (value,...): This is the same as NOT (expr IN (value,...))_". So why does not it work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Correct query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` NOT IN (10, 88, 99)
```

And your attempt with "multiple `OR`s" failed probably because of it should involve "multiple `AND`s" and negations like that:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`!=10 AND `id`!=88 AND `id`!=99
```

Comment: caution with `!=` operation. Use `<>` for this.